# 'System.ArgumentException' occured in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am new to Visual Studio and I am working with SQLite databases in my C# project. The project requires me to access my database from a network. For learning how to work with networks, I decided to use a simple server. So, I created a simple HTTP server using python and hosted my .db file in that. To access the database, I typed the following line:

```
sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=http://localhost:8000/UserDataManager.db; Version=3;Compress=True;");
sqlite_conn.Open();
```

I get the following error in the second line above and I am not able to find a way to access the database. How do I access the database?

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occured in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: URI formats aren't supported

Thank you

Comment: You get this ArgumentException because this _URI formats aren't supported_ (you can't use HTTP)

Comment: How do I access the database then?

Comment: locally. Download and use (for example). SQLite is filebased db, there is no "server".

Comment: SQLite is a file base and does not support multi user clients. You have two options here. Migrate to other RDBMS or create a web service wrapper for your SQLite db.

Comment: Okay, I get it.